# How to select first character of attribute and insert into other column of same record on same table over many rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a huge User table of almost a million records and I need to iterate over each user, grab the first character of a string in `first_name` and insert that character into `first_initial` for that record on the same User table. I'd prefer not to iterate through this via Rails because it will take hours instantiating objects etc. and so I was wondering if anyone had a good way of doing this either using  Rails' `update_all` or keeping it strictly in psql.

This outputs the chars but I'm failing at inserting them into the corresponding initial column:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(first_name, 1, 1) FROM users;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you need, you can put it in a migration or just run it from console

```
User.update_all("first_initial = SUBSTRING(first_name, 1, 1)")
```

Comment: Perfect!  I was so close yet so far lol thanks for your help.